# alert is not working due to clicking on prevent checkbox

Tags: jquery, browser

I am using google chrome as a browser and I clicked on checkbox **Prevent this type of message from next time**. Now `alert("Hi..")` is not showing. How to activate this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close your browser, and re-access the page. It will auto start alerting.

Comment: Thanx actually i am new so i didn't know.